# Create stretchy headers swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a `UIView` as a header.

I want that when the user scrolls down the header will be stretched with a stretchy header effect.

I've tried this code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        self.backgroundImageView?.frame.size.height += -scrollView.contentOffset.y
        self.backgroundImageView?.frame.size.width += -scrollView.contentOffset.y
    } 
}
```

But it has 2 problems:

- When the scrolling starts, the image isn't in the centre anymore (it keeps the 0x 0y origin I guess)
- The image keep sizing even when the releases the touch (or when he scrolls up) and doesn't returns to its original size.

Anyone can help me find a code that will work?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get the result your looking for if you use a transform to change the scale of the image.

Give something like this a try, you might want to tweak the scaleFactor to be a ratio instead of the raw value, but its going to depend on your layout.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var scaleFactor:CGFloat = 0.0
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scaleFactor = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
    } else {
        scaleFactor = 1.0
    }
    self.backgroundImageView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
}
```

Comment: It kind of work but the scale is really big, I just want a bit of scale. And when the `contentOffset` is returns to be 0 the image disappears completely instead of returning to the original size

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add an else..if the content offset is greater than or equal to 0 set the scale to 1. i'll edit the answer to fix that, for the size just try dividing the y axis content offset by something, say 10. or you can go more detailed and figure out a ratio related to the max size and offset.